# Why does ListSurfacePlot3D yield a different surface fit than using Python code for best-fit quadratic curve (2nd-order)?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, fitting, python

Using the same data, I obtain different surface fits on Mathematica (using ListSurfacePlot3D) and Python (using a code for best-fit quadratic curve (2nd-order)).
Here's my code on Mathematica:

```
data = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {4, 2, 8}, {1, 2, 5}, {3, 3,
 1}};
e = ListPointPlot3D[data];
f = ListSurfacePlot3D[data];
Show[e, f]
```

[image]

Here's my Python code (inspired from [here](http://inversionlabs.com/2016/03/21/best-fit-surfaces-for-3-dimensional-data.html)):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1,2,0,4,1,3]
y=[1,2,2,2,2,3]
z=[1,2,0,8,5,1]

data = np.c_[x,y,z]

# regular grid covering the domain of the data
mn = np.min(data, axis=0)
mx = np.max(data, axis=0)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(mn[0], mx[0], 20), np.linspace(mn[1], mx[1], 20))
XX = X.flatten()
YY = Y.flatten()

# best-fit quadratic curve (2nd-order)
A = np.c_[np.ones(data.shape[0]), data[:,:2], np.prod(data[:,:2], axis=1), data[:,:2]**2]
C,_,_,_ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, data[:,2])

# evaluate it on a grid
Z = np.dot(np.c_[np.ones(XX.shape), XX, YY, XX*YY, XX**2, YY**2], C).reshape(X.shape)

# plot points and fitted surface using Matplotlib
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.2)
ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2], c='r', s=50)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.axis('equal')
ax.axis('tight')
```

[image]

The fit on Python seems to have less details in terms of its curvature, and the overall shape is different. What could this be due to?

Comment: If you expect a universally unique "fit" to just 6 data points, you are very optimistic.  I, being not so optimistic, would prefer the software respond with "Come back when you have more data."  Also you'll notice that *Mathematica* does not fit the 3rd coordinate as a function of the first two as there is more than one value for some values of the first two coordinates.

Comment: So you believe adding many data points will yield the same surface fit? I'm trying to understand the differences in methodology used by these 2 techniques to obtain surface fits, so I first decided to use few data points to check, and there is indeed a methodological difference. Hopefully some of you will have an idea what those methodological differences are.

Comment: Many points would certainly raise the probability of a more-or-less common fit.  And I'm not well-versed enough to tell you how *Mathematica* does it.

Comment: ListSurfacePlot3D isn't really fitting a surface to the points in the way you're thinking.  It's actually closer to this paper: http://hhoppe.com/recon.pdf   (This is just the first one on the topic I found with a search; actual implementation/details may differ, etc...)